# Powershell Reg Multi_SZ into String ( Export / Import Scenario )

Tags: powershell, registry, hexdump, utf-16le

Need your help :).
Im trying to convert Roger Zanders wonderful Reg2PS into my own Powershell script which i want to use in Intune for some comfortable Registry configs.
Greetings at this point to RZ! https://reg2ps.azurewebsites.net/

I found his code here: https://github.com/rzander/Reg2CI/blob/master/Source/REG2PS/RegClass.cs

Relevant Codepart in this topic:

```
if (DataType == ValueType.MultiString)
{
//return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(_value.Replace("hex(7):", "").Replace(" ", "")));
string[] aHex = _value.Replace("hex(7):", "").Replace(" ", "").Split(',');
List<byte> bRes = new List<byte>();

foreach (string sVal in aHex)
{
bRes.Add(Convert.ToByte(sVal, 16));
}

string sResult = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bRes.ToArray());
_svalue = "\"" + string.Join(",", sResult.TrimEnd('\0').Split('\0')) + "\"";
return sResult.TrimEnd('\0').Split('\0');
}
```

So after some other people tried to translate it or write it by there own, i recognize that Roger did it overall better with Multi_SZ (Whitespaces, "", and so on).

Therefore im fine with every Type but struggle at the Multi_SZ like so many.

I export a Registry Multi_SZ with Reg.exe.

Example:

```
$PlainValue = '"MultiStringProperty"=hex(7):56,00,61,00,6c,00,75,00,65,00,31,00,00,00,56,00,\61,00,6c,00,75,00,65,00,32,00,00,00,56,00,61,00,6c,00,75,00,65,00,33,00,00,\00,00,00'

# Get the Value itself  
$Value = $PlainValue.Split("=")[1]

 # Remove Hex Descrioption
$Value = $Value.Replace( "hex(7):","" )

# Learned from a HEX to UTF16 Converter the "\" is just ja reg.exe thing to shortening the Line in the File -> Remove!
$Value = $Value.Replace("\","")
```

And now the Problem begins.
What worked for me is for Example:

```
$Value1 = $Value -split (",") | % { [INT]"0x$_" }
$Value1 = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($Value1)

$Value2 = $Value -split (",") | % { [char][byte]"0x$_" }
$Value2 = $Value2 -join ''
```

My target is to have a final format of an String as: @("Value1","Value2","Value3")

Problem:
The String i got in $Value1 or $Value2 isnt recognizing to .split(" ").

If i split before like:

```
# Splitting Hex Spaces
$Separator = ",00,00,00,"
$ArrValues = $Value -split $separator
$TempValues = @()
ForEach( $Val in $ArrValues )
{
     $Temp = $Val -split (",") | % { [INT]"0x$_" }
     [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($Temp)
     $TempValues += [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($Temp) 
}
```

Then PS has Problems to convert the Digits ...

Do i have some understanding problems or has powershell problems to convert the array?
Im trying to find a better separation instead of 00,00,00 in the mean....

Please correct me but as i know in REG_Multi_SZ there is no witespace within the value allowed right?

Comment: Are you getting an error message saying "the `Split()` method cannot be found on an object of type `[object[]]` ...", or similar?

Comment: Use join instead of split :  $value1 -join ','

Comment: No error and as you perhaps noticed by doing it by ureself join doesnt work also. Value1 is an String Array Object, Value2 is a normal String.

Comment: As an aside: `$Value -split (",") | % { [char][byte]"0x$_" } -join ''` doesn't work as you expect, because it retains the `0x0` bytes as (inivisible) NULL characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a different approach based on `-replace`, the [regular-expression-based string replacement operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator), in combination with [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) (which is by default also regex-based), which is both more concise and efficient:

```bash
# Convert the hex string to a byte array.
[byte[]] $bytes = 
  $plainValue -replace '^.+=hex\(7\):|\\' -split ',' -replace '^', '0x'

# Interpret the byte array as a Unicode string, remove the trailing NULLs,
# and split the result into individual strings by NULL
$strings = 
  [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($bytes).TrimEnd("`0") -split "`0"
```

Note:

- `-replace '^.+=hex\(7\):|\\'` replaces everything up to and including `=hex(7):` as well as (`|`) any embedded `\` (escaped as `\\`) from the input string, leaving just the "hex-byte string"

  - For an explanation of the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/TXfV2Y/1).
- `-split ','` splits the byte string into individual bytes (represented as two-digit hex strings without a prefix)
- `-replace '^', '0x'` effectively *prepends* `'0x'` to each byte representation (`^` matches the *position* at the start of each individual byte, which is where `0x`, the substitution string is placed).
- The array of resulting strings (`@('0x56', '0x00', '0x61', ...)`) is then automatically converted to `[byte]` values by PowerShell, due to the `[byte[]]` type constraint on the target variable, `$bytes`.
- `[Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($bytes)` then converts the resulting byte array to the text it represents, based on interpreting the bytes as "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) encoded.
- `` .TrimEnd("`0"`) `` removes the *trailing* NULL characters from the resulting text (`REG_MULTI_SZ` strings have *two* NULLs as terminators, to signal that no more strings are present).
- `` -split "`0" `` then splits the resulting string by the *interior* NULLs that separate the individual strings inside a `REG_MULTI_SZ` strings, yielding an array of those strings.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Splitting `$Value` by `,00,00,00,` isn't a valid way to break the byte sequences into parts that form valid UTF-16LE byte sequences.
- ASCII-range Unicode characters, such as `V` or `1`, encoded as UTF-16LE have a `0x0` byte as the second byte in the two-byte sequence that forms a single character, and if you  *remove* this byte (which is what your `-split` operation effectively does at the end of the substrings), you'll end up with an *invalid character*, which `[Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString()` represents as `�`, the [REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd)

  - More fundamentally, the assumption that the second byte in a two-byte sequences is `0x0` only holds for characters in the ISO-8859-1 subrange of Unicode, i.e. only for Unicode code points in the 8-bit subrange, `U+0000` - `U+00FF`. For characters *outside* that range, say, `€`, that second byte is *not* `0x0`.
- You can avoid having to manually break the byte sequences by `0x0 0x0` separators along proper character boundaries if you perform decoding via `[Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString()` *first*, on the *entire string*, and *then* split the resulting - properly parsed string - into substrings by NULL *characters*, [`U+0000`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0)), as shown in the solution at the top.

Comment: Well besides the decision of .replace or -replace the magic in ur recommendation is happen at the text encoding, wich solves the problem and im thankfull for that!

That the replacement of ,00 and so on isnt the finest is something i already new. but im quite new in that material and i have to figure out how it works. 
what me still confuses is, that the same operation without an array works quite fine. 
does it matter with the positioning of the "," also? dont think so. 

btw. i always did hate regex but its so powerful :)

Comment: Well ... for your replacement line. What did u expect to do with "-replace '^' because it doesnt do anything. 

The style to write ", 0x' instead of | % { ... } was also new for me but i have to say it is as always easier to read while writing it full (for not so much expierenced ps user.

Comment: lol ... yeah im a little bit tired i guess cause i dont read the "replace" properly ... sure the "," is the delmiter for the replace operator ... read it like ";" ... my bad.

So finally catching the nulls with '`0' was the missing part in my value 1 example. 

Perhaps u could also help me with some insights for [int] and [byte] in that case because int worked also fine in value1 instead of using byte. And the char operator isnt relevant isnt it?

Comment: additional to the regex ... yeah you trimmed the string down to such the value, as i do with replace in more steps. i know some operators but avoid it at all when i can :). 

 "(which is what your -split operation effectively does at the end of the substrings)"  cant follow you on that part. you mean the -split with the separator at that point?

because u used the same -split "," at the plainvalue as i do.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, @Smithy. PowerShell's regex operators are a little obscure at first, and that matching operators can operate on _arrays_ of input values individually takes some getting used to, but I think you'll benefit from learning how to use them. As for the `-split `operation: By splitting by `,00,00,00,` you're splitting not just by the NULL character that separates the entries (`00,00`), but also by the trailing  null _byte_ that is _part of each string value_. Each string value's byte sequence is therefore missing a trailing NULL, which breaks the UTF-16LE decoding

Comment: Another question for clarification: instead of writing 
[byte[]] $bytes = $plainValue -replace '^.+=hex\(7\):|\\' -split ',' -replace '^', '0x'
i trimmed the string by my own and wrote ForEach( $Hex in $($Value -split ',' ) )
                                                                {
                                                                    [byte[]]$ByteList += ( "0x" + $Hex )
                                                                } 
but when i just use compare-object it says they are different?? im a litte bit confused. why so?

Comment: Well they are for sure different because the encoder cant handle my bytlist within the for each ... im still confused. is the foreach the problem here like in the beginning? just write it with a replace regex should work different like with a foreach ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256940/discussion-between-smithy-and-mklement0).